# How to use google ecommerce to track the registrations?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, ecommerce

I am using the below code for tracking the registrations

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'website_name']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'],);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '12121212',           
    'title',  
    '1.00',         
    '',           
    '',              
    '',       
    '',     
    ''             
  ]);
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '12121212',           
    'title',
    'JOb App',        
    'Email',  
    '1.00',         
    '1'               
  ]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers

  (function() {
   ...

      })(); 
   }
```

But my confusion is, _trackPageview is having no value. Is it OK to have NO value ?

It is not reporting anything in Google analytics.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need it do not use it. It's not meant to generate pageviews. It's used to generate events.

**What is _trackPageview and how can it help me?**

> Google Analytics' _trackPageview is a function for use on ga.js
>   tracked sites that allows you to track events on your site that do not
>   generate a pageview. Using the _trackPageview JavaScript, you can
>   assign a specific page filename to Flash events, JavaScript events,
>   file downloads, outbound links, and more.